# Using multiple RabbitMQ in sequence

Tags: rabbitmq, ttl

Is it possible to use multiple rabbitMQ in sequence? For example, lets we have a case when some message is published to a queue with TTL-expire is set. Now when TTL is expired from one queue I want to push the content of the previous queue to another queue. How it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for is Dead Letter Exchanges - see https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html .
It allows you to declare where messages should go if they expire on one queue, or if they are nack'ed.